# Can't interact with div within its container

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make an interface that opens a section with multiple module that are draggable.

I started by making the skeleton of the interface using the checkbox hack to open and close the section but for some reason I cannot interact with the div inside. Whenever I put a "cursor: move;" the mouse isn't reacting or even capable of selecting the div.

I tried to give "cursor: move;" to parent elements to see which div was being interacted with and it was the ".sections" but I do not know what in that div produce this behavior.

Here is the code :

https://jsfiddle.net/7kyp3jsc/2/

```
<div class="warper">

  <form class="mode">
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="mode" value="simple" checked>
      <span>Simple</span>
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="mode" value="avance">
      <span>Avancé</span>
    </label>
  </form>
  <div class="sections">      
    <input type="checkbox" id="sections" value="sections">
    <label for="sections">Sections</label>
    <div class="winsec win1">
      <div class="tsection"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="sections">  
    <label for="sections2">Sections</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="test" value="sections2">
    <div class="winsec win2">
      <div class="tsection"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
    
    *,
    *::before,
    *::after {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    body {
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      display: flex;
      width: 100%;
      height: 200vh;
      background-color: #d3c7ae;
      flex-direction: column;
    }
    
    .warper {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      flex: 1 1 auto;
      padding: 2em 4em;
      background-color: #706c63;
      border: 3px solid blue;
    }
    
    
    .sections {
      position: relative;
      height: auto;
      display: flex;
      flex-flow: row wrap;
      margin: 0 auto;
      width: 24rem;
      border: 2px solid pink;
      transition: 0.4s;
      overflow: hidden;  
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    
    .sections label {
      border: 2px solid red;
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    
    .sections input {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      border: 2px solid yellow;
      width: 100%;
      height: 22px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    .winsec {
      pointer-events: none;
      height: 0em;
      width: 100%;
      border: 2px solid green;
      background: green;  
    }
    
    #sections:checked ~ div,
    #test:checked ~ div {
      height: 15rem;
      transition: 0.4s ease-out;
    }
    
    #sections:not(:checked) ~ div,
    #test:not(:checked) ~ div {
      height: 0rem;
      transition: 0.4s ease-out;
    }
    
    .tsection {
      height: 50px;
      width: 50px;
      background: $brown;
      cursor: move;
    }
    
    .mode {
      display: flex;
      margin: 0 auto;
      max-width: 24em;
      padding: 0 1.5em;
      border: 3px solid pink;
    }
    
    .mode,
    .mode label {
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    .mode label {
      cursor: pointer;
      position: relative;
      height: auto;
    }
    
    .mode label span {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      padding: 0.5em 2em;
      background: $brown;
      color: $beige;
      transition: 0.5s;
    }
    
    input[type=radio] {
      position: absolute;
      opacity: 0;
      height: 0;
      width: 0;
    
    }
    
    input[type=checkbox] {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    
    .mode label input:checked + span {
      opacity: 1;
      background: $green;
    }
    
    .mode label input:focus {
      outline: transparent;
    }
```

Comment: What exaclty do you mean by not being able to interact with the `div`? The `div` element normally has no interactive

Comment: You should read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API) to learn more about drag/drop.

Comment: @JonP I mean that I cannot click on it nor have anything occur on hover. The .tsections who has a "cursor: move;" property isn't turning into a move pointer (or any sort of pointer for that matter) and if I inspect it, it redirects me to .sections as if .sections was above everything as an element in position absolute and I do not understand why.

Comment: Why ` pointer-events: none;`  on the parent `winsec ` elements? This is the cause of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

As @Jon pointed out, your `pointer-event:none` is preventing you from adding any event listeners. Once you remove that, it should work as expected:

```js
document.querySelector(".winsec.win1").addEventListener("click", function() {
alert("Div 1 works");
});

document.querySelector(".winsec.win2").addEventListener("click", function() {
alert("Div 2 works too :)");
});
```

```css
$white: #FFF;
$brown: #231F20;
$beige: #FFFAF0;
$beige2: #a8a398;
$beige3: #4c4a45;
$beige4: #77736b;
$green: #7A953C;

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200vh;
  background-color: #d3c7ae;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.warper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  padding: 2em 4em;
  background-color: #706c63;
  border: 3px solid blue;
}


.sections {
  position: relative;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 24rem;
  border: 2px solid pink;
  transition: 0.4s;
  overflow: hidden;
}


.sections label {
  border: 2px solid red;
  width: 100%;
}


.sections input {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border: 2px solid yellow;
  width: 100%;
  height: 22px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.winsec {
  height: 0em;
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid green;
  background: green;
}

#sections:checked ~ div,
#test:checked ~ div {
  height: 15rem;
  transition: 0.4s ease-out;
}

#sections:not(:checked) ~ div,
#test:not(:checked) ~ div {
  height: 0rem;
  transition: 0.4s ease-out;
}

.tsection {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background: $brown;
  cursor: move;
}

.mode {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 24em;
  padding: 0 1.5em;
  border: 3px solid pink;
}

.mode,
.mode label {
  width: 100%;
}

.mode label {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  height: auto;
}

.mode label span {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0.5em 2em;
  background: $brown;
  color: $beige;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

input[type=radio] {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;

}

input[type=checkbox] {
  opacity: 0;
}

.mode label input:checked + span {
  opacity: 1;
  background: $green;
}

.mode label input:focus {
  outline: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="warper">

  <form class="mode">
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="mode" value="simple" checked>
      <span>Simple</span>
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="mode" value="avance">
      <span>Avancé</span>
    </label>
  </form>
  <div class="sections">      
    <input type="checkbox" id="sections" value="sections">
    <label for="sections">Sections</label>
    <div class="winsec win1">
      <div class="tsection"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="sections">  
    <label for="sections2">Sections</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="test" value="sections2">
    <div class="winsec win2">
      <div class="tsection"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```